# Как свой скрипт, подключить к wp?

Tags: php, wordpress

Написал небольшой скрипт на php, работающий с zip-архивами.

Сторонних библиотек скрипт не использует.
Запускается по get запросу (если тот соответствует необходимым требованиям).
Используется mod_rewrite такого вида:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^zip/([a-zA-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /openzip.php?file=zip/$1&show=$2 [L]
```

Как подключить скрипт к сайту на wp? Wp перехватывает нужный мне get запрос и редиректит на 404 страницу.

Comment: Вам нужно поставить Ваше правило выше RewriteRule . /index.php [L], так как идет проверка существует ли директория или файл на сервере, и если она не существует то идет переадрессация на index.php, я так понимаю дириктории к которой вы обращаетесь не существует

Answer (score 1):

Примерный код, экшен и функция с подключением файла, все приметивно, необходимо задать nonce для безопасности https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field

```
add_action('init', 'openzip');
function openzip(){
  if(!empty($_GET['file'])){
    // предпологаю что тут вывод хедера архива
    require_once 'openzip.php';
    die();  
  }
}
```

В .htaccess и близко не должно такого быть, смахивает на жумлу, а мы же тут говорим о WordPress, так давайте делать все красиво )))